# Elastic Search Sort with Multiple Fields issue

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

Find my setup json here for ES:

```
"properties": {
      "Type": { "type": "keyword" },
      "Name": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "RawData",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "case_insensitive"
          }
        },
     "analyzer": "rawdata_index_analyzer",
     "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
      },
      "PostalCode": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "RawData",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "rawdata_index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
      },
      "Address": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "RawData",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "case_insensitive"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "rawdata_index_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
      },
    }
```

Now Lets say I want to sort first by Name then by Address. But here is the catch the Name is not mandatory field, meaning it may be empty. In the front end this is displayed as a block of Name,Address(If name present) OR Address(If Name not present). If the Name is empty then the sort mainly shows it in the first, sorted with Address. this is followed by non empty name and Address.

This makes the sort look weird beacuse in the frontend it is one string concatenated together.

This can be fixed by creating a new index conacatenating Name and Address.
Is there a more hacky way of doing this.

```
Example we have 3 entries: (The right order should be this in the frontend)
name1 zddress1
name2 zddress2
zddress1

 but the order currently is:

zddress1 (because this has a empty '' name)
name1 zddress1
name2 zddress2
```

Comment: you index document like this {"name" : "","address" : "zddress3"} or this {"name" : "name3","address" : "zddress3"}? If you not index field empty you can use "missing" parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best and final solution, but I tried a solution with script sorting. You can give a shot for this solution maybe :

```
POST sort-sample/_doc
{
  "address": "zddress1"
}

POST sort-sample/_doc
{
  "name": "name1",
  "address": "zddress1"
}

POST sort-sample/_doc
{
  "name": "name2",
  "address": "zddress2"
}



GET sort-sample/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "string",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """if (doc['name.keyword'].size() > 0) { return doc['name.keyword'].value } else { return "z"}"""
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "address.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```